# Azure iot-hub device twin json formatting

Tags: azure-iot-hub

Reading iot device twin used to return formatted json string. Our devices deployed in field do expect formatted json. Now suddenly azure iot hub started giving plain text json string and our devices are failing to parse them. Looking for quick solution before recalling devices to fix firmware.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "plain text json string". Can you provide before and after versions?